# How to create folders from where I last left off

Tags: python, directory, sequence

I'm using python to create folders once or twice a day and I need PART of the name to be sequential from the last time I created a folder.

ie: `180208_001` (date_sequence).

I got the date part down but now I need to look at the last number and sequence that:

```
180208_001
180208_002
180209_003
etc...
```

Comment: Split it by `_`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the folder name by "_". Increment it and then use zfill method to get the desired output.

**Ex**:

```
a = "180208_001"
a = a.split("_")[-1]
print str(int(a) + 1).zfill(len(a))
```

**Output:**

```
002
```

Comment: ah thanks. How would I parse the existing folders to find the highest number in the sequence?

Comment: @user4611642. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: @Rakesh. Please don't enable this sort of question by answering.

Comment: @MadPhysicist; I was actually providing the solution to OP's original question in the top. "I need to look at the last number and sequence that"

Comment: Sorry guy. I wasn't trying to take advantage. I do a lot on my own I've just been struggling with this one. We all start somewhere. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
# string spliting 

v = "180208_001"

# spliting v into date and sequence number.
print(v.split('_'))

# ['180208', '001']


d = v.split('_')[0]  # first element of list '180208'
print(d)

s = v.split('_')[1] # second element of list '001'
print(s)

# now taking the last part from sequence

print(s[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [23]: date = "180208"

In [24]: ls
180208_001/ 180208_002/ 180209_003/

In [25]: numbers = [int(str(dir_name).split("_")[1]) for dir_name in current_path.iterdir() if current_path.is_dir()]

In [26]: max_number = max(numbers)

In [27]: new_name = "180208_{}".format(str(max_number + 1).zfill(3))

In [28]: new_name
Out[28]: '180208_004'
```

First get all dirs, and then split to find the max number, then create a new name by max number plus one.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

This function will analyze the subdirectories of a given dir and return the incremented one as string from it:

```
import os

def toIntOrNone(nr:str):
  try:
    return int(nr)
  except:
    return None


def getIncName(dirr:str, name:str, lenNr=3):
  """Returns the incremented max value of a named subdir structured 
     like name+'_'+number or returns name+'_'+ 1 padded with 0 to lenNr"""

  if not name:
      raise ValueError("name can not be empty")

  highestNr = 0
  # read all subdirs that match ...._...
  for  f in [f.path for f in os.scandir(dirr) if f.is_dir()]:
    splitted = f.split('_')
    if len(splitted) == 2:
      key = splitted[0].split("\\")[-1]
      value = toIntOrNone(splitted[1])
      if key == name and value:
        highestNr = max(highestNr, value)

  # return incremented one
  return name + "_" + str(highestNr + 1).zfill(lenNr)


print(getIncName('.',"test",5))
print(getIncName('.',"180918",5))
print(getIncName('.',None,5))
```

On a dict with `180918_003`, `180918_005`and  `180918_15tata` in it:

```
test_00001
180918_00006

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my.py", 
    print( getIncName('.',None,5 ))
  File my.py", in getIncName
    raise ValueError("name can not be empty")
ValueError: name can not be empty
```